# Message error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter

How to fix this? The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to add `!` at the end of each one of your variables, so `Uri.base.queryPrameters['token']` becomes `Uri.base.queryPrameters['token']!`
of course this is assuming that your data is not null, otherwise it would give you a runtime error.